# Counterexample to Lagrange's theorem about symmetric bilinear forms

Tags: linear-algebra

I am learning linear algebra and today I read the proof of the following result:

**Theorem:** Let $\xi:V\times V\to \mathbb{k}$ be a bilinear symmetric functional. If $\text{char}(\mathbb{k})\neq 2$ then there is canonical basis in $V$ of $\xi$, i.e. the matrix of $\xi$ in this basis is diagonal.

This is a classic result from linear algebra which is called Lagrange's theorem.

And the proof definitely uses the fact that characteristic of the field $\mathbb{k}$ is $\neq 2$, i.e. $2\neq 0$. But I have spent some time and came up with the following counterexample:

Consider the map $f:V\times V\to \mathbb{Z}_2$  with $\dim V=2$ which is defined as $f(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})=x_1y_2+x_2y_1$ where $\mathbf{x}=(x_1,x_2), \mathbf{y}=(y_1,y_2)$. It is easy to check that $f$ is symmetric bilinear function with matrix $$A=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.$$

Suppose there is a basis of $V$ such that matrix of $f$ in this basis is diagonal $A'=\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda & 0 \\
0 & \mu
\end{pmatrix}$. In matrix notation it means that $A'=C^{T}AC$ where $C=\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{pmatrix}$ with $ad-bc\neq 0$, i.e. $ad-bc=1$. Comparing an element $[A']_{12}$ and $[C^TAC]_{12}$ of both sides it follows that: $bc+ad=0$, i.e. $bc=-ad=ad$ because we are in $\mathbb{Z}_2$ but it contradicts to $ad-bc\neq 0$.

Is my reasoning correct?

Would be very grateful for any remarks!

Comment: So... not so much a "counterexample to Lagrange's theorem" as an example to show that the assumption that the characteristic is not $2$ is indeed required (or a counterexample to 'Lagrange's theorem in characteristic 2')?

Answer (score 1):

Let $K$ be a field.

The key is the existence of a bijective correspondence between the bilinear form $\phi(X,Y)=X^TAY$ and the quadratic form $Q(X)=X^TAX=\phi(X,X)$.

When $char(K)\not= 2$, that works because $\phi(X,Y)=1/2(Q(X+Y)-Q(X)-Q(Y))$.

When $char(K)=2$, that does not work because $Q$.depends only on the entries of the diagonal of $A$.